How to ensure messages are separation in the Socket
I have currently the problem, that messages are supposed to arrive separated at the server.
private Encoding _encode = Encoding.Default;

public Encoding DataEncoding
{
    get
    {
        return _encode;
    }
    set
    {
        _encode = value;
    }
}

public void Send(string data)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (this.ConnectionState != ConnectionStatus.Connected)
        {
            this.ConnectionState = ConnectionStatus.SendFail_NotConnected;
            return;
        }

        var bytes = _encode.GetBytes(data);
        SocketError err = new SocketError();
        this._client.Client.Send(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, out err);
        if (err != SocketError.Success)
        {
            Action doDCHost = new Action(DisconnectByHost);
            doDCHost.Invoke();
        }
    });
}

The function to call the Socket.Send Method is totaly basic.
A string that needs to be send looks like this

STX-MESSAGESTRING-ETX

However, if there are many strings to be send, the message gets fragmented.
The Server receives a message that looks like this:

STX-MESSAGESTRING-ETXSTX-MESSAGESTRING2-ETXSTX-MESSAGESTRING3-ETX

What is the best way to prevent this from happening? Sadly there is no flag that indicates that the socket is currently empty or something.

"Indicates the socket is currently empty" - You're writing to a continuous Stream, just like you would if you were writing to a file. Writing to that Stream is not analogous with sending a neatly packaged message. On the recipient end, there is no guarantee that some data you send is going to be received in separate reads for two sends, the same read for two sends, or across two reads for one send. You've told us very little of how much you control, but normally you would implement some kind of protocol to ensure you know the bounds of individual messages.

You'll have to write the code to do this. There are no messages at the socket layer, only bytes. A socket is neither full nor empty, it's just a connection. The class itself may or may not have a buffer.  You'll have to specify what a message is, how it starts, how it ends, whether it has fields and how they're delimited and write all the code to do this. Or NOT work at the socket layer.

I think it was Marc Gravell that said that every socket problem in the end is a framing problem. In the example, why would anyone assume there are 3 messages instead of 1 long one? Is it the length? The 4-byte sequences STX- and -ETX ? Or are these the ASCII 0x02 (STX) and 0x03 (ETX) characters? If so, the dashes aren't needed. The bytes in a message won't come all at once either. You'll have to read bytes and check their values, keeping all the bytes between 0x02 and 0x03 and decode them. You could use a single "sentinel" value too, like 0x00 (NUL) instead of start/end

Are newlines expected in the message? If not, you can use a NetworkStream over the socket and a StreamReader to read one line at a time.

Hi Panagiotia, i only have control over the Client side. The Server expects 19 comma separated values. Thats fixed. I know i have to implement something, that makes sure only one massage at a time is send, that's what i'm asking for. Yes, the STX/ETX are the ASCII codes, i just used the dashed to make it more readable here on stackoverflow. Arrow brackets getting ignored by the editor, resulting in hard to read text. Dashes are NOT existent in the string that gets send. The Server expects that the message starts with 0x02 and ends with 0x03 and in between 19 comma separated values.

I already tried to communicate with a NetworkStream, i didn't worked at all. All i achieved was a connection. Data that got send from client wasn't received by the server and data send by the server wasn't received from the client.

@Grizzy: If the server expects "messages" to arrive in different reads then the server is broken. If you cannot fix it but only have control over the client then you need to add pauses between sending of messaging in order to ensure that they are not send in separate packets (client side) or merged at the server end with previous messages in the socket buffer. How long this pause needs to be depends on how fast the server is reading the data from the socket buffer, since you have to ensure that the previous message got retrieved by the server before the new one ends up in the socket buffer.

@SteffenUllrich That is one of the ideas i had in mind but try to avoid it due to the problems comming along with the solution.

@Grizzy: I think this is the only solution unless you a) can fix the server or b) change your view of what the server actually expects. Right now you simply state that the messages are supposed to "arrive separated" but this seems to be only your interpretation and the reality might be slightly different and this might offer a better solution.

@SteffenUllrich It's actually not my interpretation, it's a fact. Changing the programming Serverside would cause to much problems, due to the fact that my client is the only client where this problem can occure. The other clients can't have this issue due to hardware reasons.

TCP is a byte stream, not a message protocol. This means there is no "natural" separation between data. Even if you would manage to send each "message" in their own TCP packet (TCP_NOELAY can help with this) they still arrive in the same socket buffer on the server side and will be merged there with any previous data still residing in the buffer in a way which removes any previous packet boundaries.
So the only way to reliably work with such a broken server would be to have a pause between sending the messages in the hope that the server will empty the socket buffer within the pause so that the new message will reside as the only data in the socket buffer.
It might be though that the server processes TCP packets directly without any socket buffer by using some user space TCP implementation or with some embedded TCP stacks for low-memory devices. In this case using TCP_NODELAY on the client side might be sufficient.

Any streaming channel will need some method to separate messages. There are a few approaches, discussed in a bit more detail in Stephen Clearys article about message framing

Use fixed length messages.
Use a delimiter.
Use a length prefix.

My preference is for length prefix, since I think this is the easiest option to get right.
In your particular case it may be that STX indicates a message start, and ETX indicates an end. But then you need to ensure that these strings are escaped in the actual message body. If this is a preexisting format you need to check the documentation. It should include information like this, including how control characters/sequences should be escaped. When reading you need to split messages, de-escape etc. This is not provided by the sockets itself.
Ofc, my real preference is to use a library that deal with message framing, error handling, and other details I rather not know about. I have used Http & MQTT, but there are lots of libraries and protocols to chose from.
